# Count values in a columns depending on value of another one column

Tags: python, product, multiple-columns

I have this issues: I have to sum all the values present in a dataframe column based on the value that I have in another column. In the specific I have a column "App" and a columns "n_of_Installs".

What I need is count all "n. of Installs" for each App.

I tried this code: `dataframe.groupby('App').sum()['n_of_Installs']` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you're almost there... `df.groupby('App')['n_of_installs'].sum()`... (so column(s) first - then the aggregate operation)

Comment: Hi Jon! thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately the results is not a df with two columns, one with the app name and one with the total sum

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input DF and what you're expecting out... and how the above doesn't do that?

Answer (score 0):

Following line will do what you want:

```
dataframe.groupby('App')['n_of_installs'].sum() # returns pandas Series
```

Note that above code returns you a pandas Series. If you wish to get a pandas DataFrame instead, use the as_index=False option of groupby

```
dataframe.groupby('App', as_index=False)['n_of_installs'].sum() # returns pandas DataFrame
```